# Cannot Register Vora Tables in Spark

Tags: vora

When attempting to register all tables in Vora with

vc.sql("REGISTER ALL TABLES USING com.sap.spark.vora")

I receive the following error

"The current Vora version does not support parallel loading of partitioned tables. Please wait until the previous partitioned tables are loaded, then issue your query again."

Is there a way of clearing all previous requests? Is there a way to clear the Vora Catalog outside of SQL command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can occur in Vora 1.2 due to a program error with incorrect handling of partitioned tables. A workaround has been documented now on the [Troubleshooting Blog](http://scn.sap.com/blogs/vora/2015/12/09/sap-hana-vora--troubleshooting#31). It is planned to address this issue with the next Vora version.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the vora-discovery and vora-dlog directories removed all metadata and we were able to recreate our tables.